# Python Scanning not Working on Docker - Hangs

Tags: python, docker, sonarqube-scan

I installed 2 docker images:

1. sonarqube:latest (it installs version 7.1 on java:8-alpine)
2. java:8-alpine image with the 3.1.0.1141 version of the
   sonar-scanner-cli (I tried also with version 3.0.3.778 and even with
   ubuntu:latest and the linux version of the cli-scanner with the
   built-in jre)

When running the scan on a java file - it works great. When running on a python file it hangs at:

```
INFO: Quality profile for py: Sonar way
INFO: Sensor Python Squid Sensor [python]
```

Anyone else have this issue, and if so how did you handle it?